# Cassandra CPU imbalance in Azure

Tags: azure, cassandra, cpu

We have a 30+ node Cassandra cluster (3.11.2) in 4 data centers.  One of the centers consists of 8 nodes in Azure running on Standard DS12 v2 (4cpu, 28gb) nodes with a 500GB premium SSD drive.  All in the same data center (central US).

We are seeing a dramatic CPU imbalance in the node activity when pushed to the max.  We have a keyspace with about 200 million records, and we're running a process to check and refresh the records if necessary from another data stream.

What's happening, is we have 4 nodes that are running at 70-90% CPU compared to 15-25% of the other 4.  The measurement of the CPU is being done in the nodes themselves, because Azure's own metrics is broken and never represents what is actually happening.

Digging into a pair of nodes (one low CPU and one high) the difference is the iowait% of the two.  The data in the keyspace is balanced (within reason - they are all within 5% of another in record count and size).  It looks like the number of reads is balanced, and even the read latency as reported by Cassandra is similar.

When I do an iostat compare of the nodes, the high CPU node is reporting a much higher (by 50 to 100%) rKB/s numbers... which is likely leading to the difference in iowait% time.

These nodes are 100% configured the same, running the same version of everything (OS, libraries, everything) that I can think to look.  I cannot figure out why some nodes are deciding to do more disk reads that the others, resulting in the cluster as a whole slowing down.

Anybody have any suggestions on where I can look for differences?

The only thing that is a pattern, is the nodes that are slower are the 4 nodes that were added later in our expansion.  We started with 4 nodes for a while and added 4 more when we needed space.  All the appropriate repairs and other tasks required with node additions were done - the fact that the records and physical size of the data files on disk being equal should attest to that.

When we shut down our refresh process, the all the nodes settle down to a even 5% or less CPU across the board.  No compaction or any other maintenance is happening that would indicate something different.

plz help... :)

Comment: What is your keyspace's RF, and what CL are you querying at?  Does this happen during reading or writing (or both)?

Comment: RF = 3.  Local Quorum.  The process is a 99% (or higher) read.  It reads to compare if an update need to be done - resulting in a subsequent write and further processing/logging.  All reads are based on the full key (Partition and sequence columns), without any ALLOW FILTERING.  We are using the latest DataStax drivers and have implemented mapper objects - all in JAVA.

Comment: We are attempting repairs and cleans on the nodes - but are running into the issue where periodically the node throw OOM errors and restart...  Once we tackle that, then back to this.  Or maybe, repairs will "fix" whatever the issue is here.

Comment: All nodes repaired.  Cleaned up.  Compacted... everything.  They are more closely balanced now, but still out of whack.  Question: might be related.  These keyspaces (there are 2 different ones) have about 200m records each. with a grand total size of about 220 GBs.  Meaning each server is responsible for 65 million records totaling about 30 GB.  Is that too much for a 4 core, 28gb RAM virtual machine?  Should we be looking at more nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our final solution for this - to fix ONLY the unbalanced problem was to cleanup, full repair and compact.  At that point the nodes are relatively equally used.  We suspect expanding the cluster (adding nodes) may have left elements of data on the older nodes that were not compacted out based on regular compaction events.

We are still working to try to solve the load issue; but now at least all the nodes are feeling the same CPU crunch.